# How do I update Andengine's entity modifiers?

Tags: android, andengine

What I'm trying to achieve is changing the mRectangles properties such as the duration when the user changes it within settings. I've read that I'm suppose to use modifier.reset() with the respective arguments from the original. I can't seem to figure out what I should pass in the fourth parameter.  Is there a variable or function that I should call to get the right context?

```
 @Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Rectangle mRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT,
            mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    // With this anonymous function, you can add events to the beginning and end
    // of the modified state
    IEntityModifierListener mIEntityModifierListener = new IEntityModifierListener() {

        @Override
        public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                IEntity pItem) {
            // Grab the current duration value and compare it to the
            // one that's stored
            final int mDuration = (int) pModifier.getDuration();
            Log.i("MODIFIER", "Current duration value: " + mDuration);

            if(mDuration != mDurationPref)
            {
                Log.i("UPDATEDURATION","Duration value: " + mDurationPref);
                mFinalDuration = mDurationPref;

                pModifier.reset();

            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("UPDATEDURATION","Both values match: " + COLORONE_DEFAULT);
                mFinalDuration = COLORONE_DEFAULT;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> pModifier,
                IEntity pItem) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("MODIFIER", "It finished!");

        }
    };

    Log.i("FINALDURATIONVALUE", "Final duration: " + mFinalDuration);
    // This is where you can chain up the colors
    // TODO: Make this in to a function that interpolates the colors together
    ColorModifier mColorModifier = new ColorModifier(5, Color.CYAN,
            Color.RED, mIEntityModifierListener, EaseSineIn.getInstance());
    ColorModifier tColorModifier = new ColorModifier(5, Color.RED,
            Color.CYAN, EaseSineInOut.getInstance());
    ColorModifier iColorModifier = new ColorModifier(5, Color.CYAN,
            Color.GREEN, mIEntityModifierListener, EaseSineIn.getInstance());
    ColorModifier xColorModifier = new ColorModifier(5, Color.GREEN,
            Color.YELLOW, EaseSineInOut.getInstance());
    ColorModifier yColorModifier = new ColorModifier(5, Color.YELLOW,
            Color.CYAN, mIEntityModifierListener, EaseSineIn.getInstance());

    // The sequence modifier will go through the color modifiers
    // and the loop entity modifier makes it continuous 
    SequenceEntityModifier mSequenceEntityModifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(
            mColorModifier, tColorModifier, iColorModifier, xColorModifier,
            yColorModifier);
    LoopEntityModifier mLoopEntityModifier = new LoopEntityModifier(
            mSequenceEntityModifier);

    mRectangle.registerEntityModifier(mLoopEntityModifier);

    scene.attachChild(mRectangle);

    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking a bit?  You mention your goal is "changing the mRectangles properties such as the duration," but a Rectangle doesn't have a duration property.  If you mean changing the duration of the modifier, why not just no pass in a hardcoded value? (i.e., the constructors for your colormodifiers all have hardcoded 5 second durations).

Comment: Yes, it's hardcoded in initially but I'm allowing the user to change the color and duration properties in the preference activity. That's why I'm using the modifier's interface method. So, that I can check properties, when it's running in the thread. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: So what is your question?  How to replace the number 5 with a variable?

Comment: How do I adjust the Entity modifier? I've tried clearing and adding another color modifier but that didnt work out.  From what I've been reading, you're suppose to use the  same arguement relative to the modifier: modifier.reset(newDuration,color1,color2, mEntityModifier, Easefunc()). The fourth arguement, 'mEntityModifier' is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you asking how do you stop an entity modifier that's already in progress?

Comment: No, more like changing the color and duration values while in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways you can do this.  Either you can play around with overriding the built in methods in the modifiers (i.e., you can @override onUpdate()) and do your own logic there, or you can do it the easier way: strip the existing modifiers and stack on the new ones.

You mentioned in the comments, "I've tried clearing and adding another color modifier but that didnt work out," but didn't elaborate on why.  If you mean you received some error, post the error message and we can discuss it.  If what you mean is you're not getting a "smooth" transition from the existing color to the new color (which would make sense), what you should do is have the new modifier start from the current existing values.  In other words, when doing the color modifier you feed it a "From" and a "To" color, use mRectangle.getColor() as the "From" so you can start the transition from wherever you currently are.

Comment: Ah, I will rewrite everything using other methods and throw the logic in there. I think I'm going to try to see if onManagedUpdate() for mRectangle will work. I tried using clearing the modifier and it only worked once because I used another nested modifier listener to start it over again. I think my logic was flawed at that point.  I appreciate your feedback. Thank you so muck. I will report back.

Comment: @wavyGravy Cool.  Let us know how it works.  Also, please consider giving the green acceptance check mark if this answer helped you.

Comment: I got it to update properly. Turns out that I didn't need to use that method with the fourth unknown argument at all. I just had to clear it and start a new stack of Entity Modifiers within onModifierStarted(). I must have been on crack when I was testing. Thank you!